# Unable to append data to table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to append data on submit but I keep on getting this error.

> Line 53:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression  no-unused-expressions

I am trying to append data submitted by the user to append to table as td.
What am I doing wrong or Is there any better way to do it.

Here is the code

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const Table = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState({ name: "", email: "" });
  const [obj, setObj] = useState([]);
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setObj([...obj, { name: count.name, email: count.email }]);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    setCount(count => ({ ...count, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
  };

  console.log(count);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Add Name"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            value={count.name}
            required
          />
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Add Email"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            value={count.email}
            required
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Add" className="btn btn-dark" />
        </form>
        <table className="table-striped">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            {obj.length !== 0 &&
              obj.map(item => {
                <tr key={item.id}>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.email}</td>
                </tr>;
              })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your `map` method. Either use return:

```
obj.map(item => {
  return (
    <tr key={item.name}>
    <td>{item.name}</td>
    <td>{item.email}</td>
  </tr>
  );
})
```

or use [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body):

```
obj.map(item => (
  <tr key={item.name}>
    <td>{item.name}</td>
    <td>{item.email}</td>
  </tr>
))
```

**Edit after comment**

You are getting the key warning since there isn't any `item.id`. I used `item.name`. You should choose better keys of course.

Comment: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: This is another problem and you can find the solution easily :) I'm going to fix that warning in my answer but it is a good habit to search your problems.

Comment: I know but this problem took a while for me and a simple return statement could have solved that. Name may be repetitive should I use some index?

Comment: If you are sure that the order of the array won't change then you can use the index as a key but generally, it is not advisable. You can create `id`s when you create your data by using [something like this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) maybe.